# How to enumerate CFProperyList / CFDictionary keys

Tags: ios, macos, enumeration, core-foundation

I would like to iterate through a CFDictionary (CFPropertyList) and get all values on a specific level.

This would be my dictionary / property-list:

```
 root
 
  A
  
   foo
   0
   bar
   0
  
  B
  
   foo
   10
   bar
   100
  
  C
  
   foo
   20
   bar
   500
```

Using ObjC it would look something like this:

```
//dict is loaded with the dictionary below "root"
NSDictionary *dict = [...];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dict keyEnumerator];
NSString *key;
while (key = [enumerator nextObject]) 
{
    NSLog(key);
};
```

And it would print out a list of keys to the console like this:

```
A
B
C
```

**How do you achieve this when using C/C++ on the CoreFoundation-level?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on code from [SeeMyFriends](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SeeMyFriends/listing7.html):

```
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(...)
size size = CFDictionaryGetCount(dict);
CFTypeRef *keysTypeRef = (CFTypeRef *) malloc( size * sizeof(CFTypeRef) );
CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues(dict, (const void **) keysTypeRef, NULL);
const void **keys = (const void **) keysTypeRef;
```

You can now walk through the pointers in `keys[]`. Don't forget to `free(keys)` when you're done.

Remember that dictionary keys are not strings. They're `void*` (which is why they took the trouble of casting `keysTypeRef` into `keys`). Also note that I've only grabbed keys here, but you could also get values at the same time. See the SeeMyFriends code for a more detailed example.

Comment: The CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues method takes a pointer to a pointer to an array of the keys. Why, then, do you not pass the address of the "keysTypeRef" pointer (which would be a pointer to that pointer)?

Comment: `CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues` takes a a pointer to an array of pointers (`void **`), not a pointer to a pointer to an array of pointers (`void ***`). Remember, `CFTypeRef` itself is a pointer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? That link is down.

Comment: See KennyTM's answer, which is an easier approach than doing this by hand.

Comment: If you don't only want to print the values (or print them nicer), you might have to check for the type of every property. An example of that is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17981965/1904815.

Answer (score 49):

Use `CFDictionaryApplyFunction` to iterate through a dictionary.

```
static void printKeys (const void* key, const void* value, void* context) {
  CFShow(key);
}
...
CFDictionaryApplyFunction(dict, printKeys, NULL);
```

Comment: Agreed. An excellent approach for a wide variety of problems.

Answer (score 5):

CFCopyDescription is helpful when Debugging...

```
CFCopyDescription
Returns a textual description of a Core Foundation object.

    CFStringRef CFCopyDescription (
       CFTypeRef cf
    );
```